# Catching self in moments of stress

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say someone has a tendency to react right away to moments of stress but then after it has been noticed or pointed out, he/she forms meditation habit and after some time, doesn't have such tendency instead having awareness like 'Hey this person/event/noun is leading me to be distracted/stressed out. I shouldn't react right away.'

We say this person became less impulsive or more...

Conscious? Cautious? I'm not sure the [antonyms here work](http://www.synonyms.net/antonyms/impulsive).

...I'm thinking self-aware, but it seems to be applicable more for planned times of meditation, self-review, etc than for unplanned stressors.

Then it would seem that during meditation, one is not training to be self-aware but rather being self-aware but then training to be...?

Comment: We would say this person gained *composure*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this person's reactions have become more ***controlled***.

From [macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/controlled_1):

> **controlled**
>   adjective
>
> 1 calm and showing no emotion even though you are angry or upset
>   *She gave a cool, controlled smile, then left.*

Comment: (Edited question but your answer is still applicable I think) Ah so the person was self-aware during meditation and then eventually improved in self-control in moments of stress?

Comment: Also, 'Had more *self*-control'

Answer (score 0):

*They become **able to self-distance**.*

> The ability to critically reflect on oneself and one's relations from an external perspective.
>   *Ironic humor is an instance of the more general phenomenon of self-distance* (Contemporary Philosophy of Social Science, By Brian Faypage, Page 33)
>   - https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-distance

Comment: (Edited question but your answer is still applicable I think) 1. Are you sure that applies to spontaneous/impromptu/unplanned events? That sounds like self-awareness where that's more for planned stuff like when I meditate, I have ability of self-distance but am training to ...? Be more cautious? conscious? Or meditation is training for self-distance? 2. What do you think of Davo's 'controlled' ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deliberate

**deliberate**

adjective

1 Done consciously and intentionally.
‘a deliberate attempt to provoke conflict’

2 Careful and unhurried.
‘a conscientious and deliberate worker’

**2.1 Fully considered; not impulsive.**
‘a deliberate decision’

you could also just use **considered**